# How to plot the relative and absolute frequencies

Tags: r, statistics

I have a list of dates

```
> (length(list$date))
[1] 36799
```

I want to make a `relative and absolute frequencies analysis` and plot this frequencies of dates on a timeline.

How can I implement this in R?

**UPDATE**

My data looks like that

```
> (dput(head(ddListData$MELDE_DATUM, 35)))
c("18.12.2003", "06.04.2005", "06.04.2005", "07.04.2005", "27.05.2005", 
"16.06.2009", "16.06.2009", "21.12.2009", "22.12.2009", "09.06.2011", 
"14.06.2011", "20.12.2011", "20.12.2011", "04.02.2008", "27.03.2009", 
"01.04.2009", "15.12.2009", "23.09.2005", "19.06.2005", "20.06.2005", 
"20.06.2005", "20.06.2005", "21.06.2005", "31.05.2005", "24.01.2007", 
"24.01.2007", "24.01.2007", "15.05.2007", "16.05.2007", "16.05.2007", 
"18.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "22.05.2007", "22.05.2007"
)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking and you don't provide reproducible data nor the expected result nor what you have tried. I can only point you to `hist`.

Comment: @Roland pls see my update. At the moment I am struggeling with methods to do this analysis. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c("18.12.2003", "06.04.2005", "06.04.2005", "07.04.2005", "27.05.2005", 
  "16.06.2009", "16.06.2009", "21.12.2009", "22.12.2009", "09.06.2011", 
  "14.06.2011", "20.12.2011", "20.12.2011", "04.02.2008", "27.03.2009", 
  "01.04.2009", "15.12.2009", "23.09.2005", "19.06.2005", "20.06.2005", 
  "20.06.2005", "20.06.2005", "21.06.2005", "31.05.2005", "24.01.2007", 
  "24.01.2007", "24.01.2007", "15.05.2007", "16.05.2007", "16.05.2007", 
  "18.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "22.05.2007", "22.05.2007"
)

hist(as.Date(x, '%d.%m.%Y'), breaks="days", freq=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! One further question is is also possible to get a table with the frequencies?

Comment: `as.data.frame(hist(as.Date(x, '%d.%m.%Y'), breaks="days")[c( "mids", "counts")])` maybe?